# VBA excel executar ação a partir de seleção do dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, macro

Fala pessoal, boa tarde, tudo certo?

Vim pedir ajuda aos universitários pois to quebrando a cabeça a dias e não estou conseguindo resolver meu problema.

Basicamente tenho esta tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão de novo cadastro, automaticamente a primeira lista (B2) abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu queria é que no momento em que seleciono alguma opção deste dropdown que abre automático, o próximo (C2) também abrisse automaticamente, no momento da seleção de B2.

Estou utilizando isso no VBA para realizar a abertura do primeiro dropdown:

```
Sub AdicionaConta()
  Range("a2").EntireRow.Insert
  Range("B2").Select
  SendKeys "%{down}"    
End Sub
```

Desde já agradeço, um abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salve!

O evento que detecta alterações em determinado campo é o `Change` do objeto `Worksheet`.

Se a rotina `AdicionaConta` já estiver no código do objeto `Worksheet` dessa planilha específica, é só adicionar o evento, como por exemplo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) ' O evento nos traz o objeto target, do tipo Range, que é a Range que foi alterada
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then ' Se foi alterada uma célula só E isso ocorreu na coluna 2 (que é a B), então faça o seguinte:
        Range("C2").Select ' Coloquei o número 2 porque foi a linha que você utilizou como exemplo, mas imagino que você vá usar ali uma variável com o número da linha que você tem que ajustar.
        SendKeys "%{down}"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Muito obrigado César, exatamente isso que eu tava tentando fazer. Agora próximo passo é fazer para a coluna D, porem nem todas as opções da coluna C tem opçoes, entao acredito que precise fazer um outro if.

Comment: Retificando, já consegui!!! Muito obrigado pelo ajuda César!!

Comment: Marca minha resposta como a correta, então.

Comment: Opa, pensei que nao conseguia por ser usuário novo. Já foi marcada!